# Posting to FB wall using Facebook C# SDK fails after July 25, 2011

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I was able to post messages to my wall through Facebook application with ASP.NET web application and Facebook C# SDK. I had a never expiring access token and it was working fine till July 25, 2011. It was reset by FB for some security related reasons. So I changed my code to get the access token on the fly using the following piece of code.

```
        string url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=app_id&client_secret=app_secret&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=offline_access,publish_stream";

        HttpWebRequest webRequest = null;
        StreamWriter requestWriter = null;
        string responseData = "";
        webRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
        webRequest.Timeout = 20000;
        StreamReader responseReader = null;

        if (webRequest.Method == "POST")
        {
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            //POST the data.  
            requestWriter = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream());

            requestWriter.Write(string.Empty);

            responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
            responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
            accessToken = responseData.Substring(responseData.IndexOf("=") + 1, responseData.Length - responseData.IndexOf("=") - 1);
        }
```

and I perform the posting by using

```
        if (accessToken.Length > 0)
        {
            url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=" + accessToken;
        }

        var client = new FacebookClient();

        dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
        if (!(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtMessage.Text) & String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtMessage.Text)))
        {
            parameters.message = txtMessage.Text;
        }
        parameters.link = "";
        parameters.picture = "";
        parameters.name = "";
        parameters.caption = "";
        parameters.description = "";
        parameters.actions = new
        {
            name = "",
            link = "",
        };
        parameters.privacy = new
        {
            value = "ALL_FRIENDS",
        };
        parameters.targeting = new
        {
            countries = "",
            regions = "",
            locales = "",
        };
        try
        {
            dynamic result = client.Post("me/feed", parameters);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblError.Text = ex.Message;
        }
```

I get the following exception "(OAuthException) An active access token must be used to query information about the current user." Something got changed after July 25,2011?

I googled a lot to find a solution for this, but nothing resolved my issue.

Thanks in advance!
MANOOH

Comment: instead of using manual http request for https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token, you could try using FacebookOAuthClient.ExchangeCodeForAccessToken